# How do I create a script for this?

Tags: html, input, download, upload, output

I am trying to take 2 media files and merge them together to become 1 media file. The problem is that whenever I upload 2 files from my computer, nothing happens. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
<p><form action="/action_page.php"><label for="myfile"><font size="6"> Choose a file </font></label><input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"><br><br><output type="submit"</form></p>
<p><form action="/action_page.php"><label for="myfile"><font size="6"> Choose a file </font></label><input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"><br><br><output type="submit"</form></p>
<p><form method="get" action="file.doc"><label for="myfile"><button type="submit" onclick="window.open('file.doc')">Download!</button></form></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how HTML forms work.
Your `action` parameter should point to a backend (PHP, NodeJs, C#, Java... the options are plentiful), and that backend will process what you've uploaded.

The best you could do right now to eliminate the requirement of a backend to handle your form inputs is to use some lib on your frontend to perform what you want (I'm sure there's some jQuery plugin that'd enable you to do so).